# Unable to obtain Google Maps API Key

Tags: android, api-key

I'm trying to obtain Google Maps API Key for my app, to use some map features.

I followed all the instructions by letter, which can be found 
[here](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey).

The problems is that the result printed in my cmd is :

Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): A4:FF:7A:D0:8A:51:20:92:98:B2:C4:35:C7:8A:46:87:
AB:7E:41:F1

I guess an appropriate result should be (MD5) instead of (SHA1). Can anyone help over here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are using just include a paramet -v in that command, you will get the MD5 Hash key.

i.e.

```
$ keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -v
```

Comment: heyyyyyyy thnx a lotttttt :) :) :)
I'll vote up when i'm able to ;)

Answer (score 0):

My Friend 
ChecK Whether Your JDK and JRE Version is same in your computer
If not You Cannot be able to generate the API Key .........
Properly My Friend